# Header Search Path for local pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

My Podfile looks like this

pod 'NSNumber+Toolbox', :path => '~/Documents/iPhoneDev/Projects/Helper/NSNumberToolbox'

but importing the header via #import "NSNumber+Toolbox.h" doesn't work as the file is not found.

What's wrong with the Podfile?

EDIT:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|  
  s.name         = "NSNumber+Toolbox"  
  s.version      = "0.0.1"  
  s.summary      = "NSNumber category."  
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/HHuckebein/NSNumberToolbox"  
  s.license      = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE.txt' }  
  s.author       = { "RABE_IT Services" => "info@berndrabe.de" }  
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/HHuckebein/NSNumberToolbox.git", :tag => "0.0.1" }  
  s.platform     = :ios, '6.0'  
  s.source_files = 'NSNumberToolbox/NSNumber+Toolbox.{h,m}'  
  s.requires_arc = true  
end
```

Comment: what about the podspec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This spec works perfectly for me. Make sure your local source folder is in the same structure as the repo itself. Also make sure you're using the newest version of CocoaPods (`[sudo] gem update`)

Comment: CocoaPods 0.20.2 Got the header file under /Pods/BuildHeaders/NSNumber+Toolbox/NSNumber+Toolbox.h respectively under /Pods/Headers/.. Just found that #import <> works but not #import "". I'm pretty sure it worked before?! What do you exactly mean by make sure ... your local source folder is in the same structure as the repo itself?

Comment: I meant that since you're using a local path for the source (which you don't have to do) it needs to be in the same structure for your `source_files` otherwise it may not link them correctly. After that once you open the `xcworkspace` you should be good to go. Try removing the `:path` part in your `Podfile` and see if it works correctly.